# Intel HD 2000 windows 10 graphics drivers

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card, intel-graphics

According to [this chart](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/graphics-drivers/000005526.html) there is no driver support for a core i3-2100 on windows 10. I would really like to get the driver for this so I can properly use the 2 video outputs on my motherboard. (Currently they are stuck as mirrored and at 800x600).

Is there some 3rd party or beta driver I can download, or maybe an intel one that isn't mentioned on the chart?

Comment: What you want does not exist

Comment: was wondering if something like this http://leshcatlabs.net/unifl-unified-leshcat-drivers/ would work

Comment: Those are AMD drivers not Intel drivers.

Comment: it mentiones intel in the description as well, even though the name is amd

Comment: The Intel portion of the drivers have not been updated in 2 years.  I see no reason these drivers would work on Windows 10 with your hardware.

Comment: When you download the drivers, it mentions windows 10, and there is a windows 10 option so they must have just not updated the "updated on..." message

Comment: As someone who spent weeks looking for non-existent drivers, I commend my solution: buy a cheap graphics card which has W10 support and the outputs you require. It will be a small price to pay to save hours of unproductive frustration.

Comment: @AFH lol, love the solution, however this doesn't work in this case as I already have a graphics card in the system. the reason i still want the intel drivers is so that I can run a total of 4 displays combining both cards as I could do in windows 7

Comment: UniFL is for switchable amd-intel graphics. [Intellimodder32](https://www.intellimodder32.com/) is what you are probably looking for isolated IGPs.

Answer (score 1):

There's an unofficial driver called UniFL, what you need to do is go over to http://leshcatlabs.net/downloads_unfil/
then, download the latest version, open the file, go to advanced, make sure the "intel hd graphics(modern) option is selected and press "Deploy", then go over to where the installers were deployed and look for the intel folder, inside it there's another folder whose name ends with "win10"(for me it was "C:\Drivers\Catalyst_15.11_Beta_UnifL_v1.0\Intel\9.17.10.4229\9.17.10.4229_win81_win10")
Open it and run Setup.exe, then you're done.

I stumbled upon it after searching for over a month, and it seems to be working for me with my i5-2310(intel HD2000)

Actually, you might want to navigate to "C:\Drivers\Catalyst_15.11_Beta_UnifL_v1.0\Intel\9.17.10.4229\9.17.10.4229_win7_win81" and install that driver instead, it seems to be working better than the other one and even makes the "Graphics properties" intel driver option show up when right clicking the windows desktop

Comment: thank you for this. I have just done exactly that right before i saw your answer, lol. I will update you on if it worked or not

Comment: well, the driver installed and the screen flashed, but it has appeared to make no difference whatsoever. I will upvote this as it was a potential answer and I don't think it should have been downvoted.